# typical gamma spectrum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spectroscopy

I have a positron emission tomography experiment and for the preparation of this experiment I have to discuss a typical gamma spectrum.

[image: typical gamma spectrum]

The x-axis is the pulse height and the y-axis is the counting rate. I've identified the marks as follows:

1. full energy peak
2. full energy peak
3. single escape peak
4. double escape peak
5. compton edge
6. compton edge
7. backscatter peak

But what is #8? Is it a peak caused by electron-positron-annihilation resulting in the detection of two photons with an energy of $511 \text{keV}$?

Comment: Gammas from innihilation go in opposite directions. It depends on the geometry of the detector, but normal detectors do not see both gammas. But hint: compare the energy of #8 to the escape peaks.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add. I have two detectors in this experiment which are placed in an $180^\circ$ angle to each other so that I can detect coincident photons.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag for questions from school assignments.

Comment: Is the x-axis in $\rm keV$, or arbitrary units?

Comment: There was no additional information given. I assume they are arbitrary units because the difference from the full energy peak to the single escape peak is about $400$ instead of $500$ units. @Pieter I noticed that the pulse height of #8 is about the same as the difference of the escape peaks' pulse height. In terms of energy it would be $511 \text{keV}$. But  I don't think that you meant this by "compare the energy of #8 to the escape peaks" because this leads me to my initial assumption.

Comment: Well, it seems you did not get the hint. Too much help with homework is discouraged on this site. It is you who is supposed to work and learn.